# In ConTeXt, how do you restart paragraph enumeration?

Tags: numbering, context

I can create paragraph enumerations, such as below, but how can I restart the numbering?

```
\setupparagraphnumbering[state=start,distance=0pt]

First paragraph, which is numbered.

Second paragraph, also numbered.

\setupparagraphnumbering[state=stop]

This paragraph isn't numbered.

\setupparagraphnumbering[state=start]

I want this paragraph to be numbered at one, rather than continuing the previous enumeration, but how do I do it?

\setupparagraphnumbering[state=stop]
```

Comment: Use `state=reset`.

Answer (score 4):

Further to Marco's comment above, I am able to restart the numbering with the command:

```
\setupparagraphnumbering[state=reset]
```